# Why am I able to assign a variable to $rootScope in an Angular controller and access it in the template, but not if I assign the variable to $scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the Angular UI Router as my router. I have a $state defined as such:

```
$stateProvider.state('mypage', {
     url:'/', 
     views: { 
         'content': { 
              templateUrl: 'folder/mypage.template.html', 
              controller: 'MyPageController' 
          }
      }
})
```

I can go to MyPageController and do the following:

```
$rootScope.test = "hello!";
```

And then go to folder/mypage.template.html and put the following:

```
<div id="example">
    {{test}}
</div>
```

hello! will show up in the rendered web page. However, if I instead do the following in MyPageController:

```
$scope.test = "hello!";
```

Nothing will show up in the template. This is very confusing to me, as I know that MyPageController is made available to the state (as I can add something to $rootScope and display it), but the $scope is not available. Does anyone have an idea as to what might be going on? Thank you :)

EDIT1:
MyPageController is part of a module, let's say myModule, that is imported into a top-level module. For example, it looks something like this:

```
angular.module('topLevelModule', [
    'myModule'
]).config( ... $stateProvider stuff ... ).run( ... setup stuff ... )

angular.module('myModule')
    .controller('MyPageController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        $scope.test = "hello!";
    }]);
```

EDIT2 (problem solved):

I had followed a tutorial that used the following pattern with multiple states in the UI-Router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('mainpage', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'folder/mainpage.template.html',
                controller: 'MainPageController' <-- POINT OF INTEREST 1
            }
        }
    })
    .state('mypage', {
        url: 'my-page',
        controller: 'MyPageController', <-- POINT OF INTEREST 2
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'folder/mypage.template.html',
                <-- POINT OF INTEREST 3
            }
        }
    })
}])
```

However, the problem lies in this formatting. This is just a heads up for anyone using the UI-Router who happened to follow the same tutorial as I did (I can't find the link), that POINT OF INTEREST 2 needs to be moved to POINT OF INTEREST 3 for the controller to properly be assigned upon state change -- syntax error. There were more complexities to why things were happening (due to my debugging approach) that were causing any inconsistencies you see above, but I won't include them here. Thanks everyone for their time. :)

Comment: are you injecting $scope as a dependency in MyPageController ?

Comment: Yes I am. I left that detail out. But that's a good thought to check that.

Comment: But why are you using 2 modules? Do you have to do that?

Comment: I am going to update the question in a couple minutes here with new information. Stay tuned, and thanks for your help :)

Comment: Added an answer of how the basic case goes, feel like your doing something more complicated?

Comment: $rootScope is used in .run functions, and in .run function $scope doesn't work, so you're doing something weird there

Comment: there is not enough code here to reproduce the issue you are describing, and what you are saying is occurring here doesn't make any sense without guessing at missing pieces of your application structure.  You should try to [edit] your question a bit more and provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's my first submitted question (I think), and I thought I would try to keep it simple. But, I've learned that I should be able to do that minimal, complete and verifiable example in the future if I want people to help.

Comment: It's good that in your attempt to provide a complete example, you were able to spot the mistake in the code.  This is a common thing to happen, and one of the reasons that posting complete examples is the first step to finding a solid solution.  Also, it would have been impossible for anyone to provide an answer, since the error was in code not originally provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.run(function() {    
});

test.config(function() {
// your state for binding html with controller
});

test.controller('MyPageController ', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = "hello!";
});
```

And then in HTML

```
<div id="example">
    {{test}}
</div>
```